# Drop down menu goes below the web content

Tags: html, css

I changed the image slider in this website:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~FluidLab/

However, I see the image slider is on the top of the menu. How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: please post code or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the elements are `position: absolute`, they have a z-index that is larger than the dropdowns automatically.

Simply add `z-index: -1` to `#slider1Content`.

Comment: Thank you it made the drop down menu on the top. However, when I was pointing the cursor to it's links,it was getting disappeared suddenly. I also added the one that Peter said. Then All together worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you add z-index:-1 to #slider1Content the drop down, although it appears visible on top of the slider disappears when you hover over it.

So add z-index:-1 to #slider1 instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was also required.